# missing artifact for oracle

Tags: oracle, maven, spring-boot, ojdbc

I am using spring boot for my application.
I am facing problem in getting connected to the oracle database. I added dependency as below.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
     <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
     <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

It gives me error `missing artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2` 
I tried to resolve this by downloading the jar into my root folder and executing the following command in the root folder of my project.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar  -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I am getting the error as below

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.4.0.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.erp.tch:processingsystem:0
.1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-p
arent:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.44.215] fail
ed: Connection refused: connect and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local
POM @ line 10, column 13@
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.erp.tch:processingsystem:0.1.0:0.1.0 (C:\TIPS\wo
rkspace\tipsredesign\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.erp.tch:processingsystem:0.1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-start
er-parent:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven
2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.44.215]
failed: Connection refused: connect and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong lo
cal POM @ line 10, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException

[ERROR] [Help 2]}
```

I tried to resolve above by adding below,still no luck.

```
<relativepath>../pom.xml</relativepath>
```

Comment: What is on line 10 of your pom?  The jdbc driver was installed locally with `com.oracle` as the groupId  (`-DgroupId=com.oracle`), but referenced in the dependency as `com.oracle.jdbc` (`<groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>`). Probably should use the same groupId.  Why the relative path? Are you building multiple modules?

Comment: resolved the issue by changing groupid from <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId> to <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>. Thank you appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jdbc driver was installed locally with groupId `com.oracle`:

```
-DgroupId=com.oracle
```

but referenced in the dependency with groupId `com.oracle.jdbc`:

```
<groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
```

The installed and referenced groupId should be consistent.